# CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response headers appear for local but not docker container

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, nginx, cors

can anyone help me solve this issue?

I'm running a php Laravel backend with fortify and sanctum for auth. I also have a React frontend which makes api calls to this backend, both of these are dockerized. If I run the php server locally, there are no issues with CORs. But once the backend is running via a docker container, the following issue pops up:
[CORS Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS2jl.png)

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/tickets' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

On the network tab, we see that the Request URL doesn't have the following fields in the Response Headers:
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
Is there a way to have two docker containers allow CORs?

What I have tried:

- Setting up an NGINX container to act as a reverse proxy, including addition of fields in:

```
location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Content-Type';

        set $nextjs nextjs_upstream;
        proxy_pass http://$nextjs;
    }
```

- Added all the required CORS fields in my config files for the server i.e. cors.php file.

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['*', 'api/*', 'login', 'logout', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'api/tickets'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost','*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['X-Custom-Header', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests','*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

Note: This attempt specifically might make sense since localhost in "allowed_origins" refers to that of within the container, but how would we change it to be outside the container? Would it be that container's IP address or something?

- Added additional installations in php Dockerfile: `"&& a2enmod headers \ && sed -ri -e 's/^([ \t]*)(<\/VirtualHost>)/\1\tHeader set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"\n\1\2/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf"`

Interestingly, my login/logout routes don't face the same CORS error which plagues my route: api/tickets, but this is besides the point since It seems like more of an issue with docker containers attempting to communicate.

Note: localhost has no port since NGINX serves the yarn/npm build.

Laravel Dockerfile:

```
# The base image
FROM php:8.0.2 as base
# Install system dependencies i.e. Zip , curl:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip

# Get extensions for PHP & Install Postgres
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
# Get the latest composer:
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy everything to the working directory
COPY . /app

# Set the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies for laravel
COPY composer.json ./
RUN composer install

# Move the exec file to our workdir and give permissions
COPY docker-init.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-init.sh

# Expose internal port which will be mapped
EXPOSE 8000
# Run our server
ENTRYPOINT [ "docker-init.sh" ]
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as build

# Set the current working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install --global pm2

# Get all dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Copy everything to the working directory
RUN npm install --force --production
RUN yarn add --dev typescript @types/react
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

# Expose internal port which will be mapped
EXPOSE 3000

USER node

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
# Prod environment
FROM nginx:alpine

# Remove any existing config files
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Copy config files
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if a pipeline returns a non zero status
set -e

# Change to our working directory
cd /app

# php artisan migrate
# Serve for all IPv4 addresses:
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Thanks for the help lads

Comment: You can't allow credentials and `*` origins

Comment: Alright, I removed that from the nginx conf file. Same error, but don't think NGINX is the problem here  :(

Comment: FYI you also have it in your `cors.php` file. So is your Laravel service running in a container that exposes port 8000? If you've set up CORS correctly in that service, you shouldn't need a reverse proxy

Comment: So would I set "supports_credentials" to false? And yep, the laravel server runs on a separate Dockerfile, called via docker-compose. I have edited my original post to include it

Comment: _"So would I set "supports_credentials" to false?"_... That depends on if you want to support cross-origin request cookies or not. If so, then keep it `true` and don't use `*` in the allowed origins

Comment: Same issue :(, Wouldn't I have to replace "http://localhost" in 'allowed_origins' with the docker container's IP? Since that localhost address is just within the same container.

Comment: No, the origin is the host of the URL open in your browser. If you have `http://localhost/` in the browser address bar, then that's your origin

Comment: Ahh alright makes sense, any idea as to why it may work locally with command `php artisan serve` and not via docker-compose? Anything to do with the docker bridge network

Comment: I have no idea. What does the `docker-init.sh` script do? Are you binding the host port 8000 to the appropriate container port?

Comment: this is the docket-init.sh: 
```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if a pipeline returns a non zero status
set -e

# Change to our working directory
cd /app

# php artisan migrate
# Serve for all IPv4 addresses:
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, had to make a change to the app/Http/kernel.php file. Basically in the lines, I had to make 'web' and 'api' the same:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Becomes:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```